# how to render entirely different css and html based upon the device size?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

In the same page I want to load screen 1  for desktop and screen 2 for mobile devices.

screen 1 - desktop   | simple bootstrap scaffolding  | radio button

[image]

Here's the code for the desktop html page, and below is the code for the mobile. But I want to merge both the codes into one.

Any guidance/ direction on how to make it on same page would be great!

```
<body>


  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                   <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Elite - d<br>         
                        </h4>
                    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <table class="table">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        10 Days of Cloud options
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        Up to 15 Cameras
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        Unlimited Support
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        $44 99 / Mo
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>



        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Premier - d<br>            
                        </h4>
                    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <table class="table">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        10 Days of Cloud options
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        Up to 15 Cameras
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        Unlimited Support
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        $44 99 / Mo
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>



        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male"> Basic - d<br> 

                        </h4>
                    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <table class="table">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        10 Days of Cloud options
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        Up to 15 Cameras
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        Unlimited Support
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        $44 99 / Mo
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>





    </div>
</div>




</body>
</html>
```

screen 2 - mobile |  uses bootstrap accordian

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>



  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close">
                            </span>Elite</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <table class="table">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        60 Days of Cloud Recording
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        Up to 15 Cameras
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        Unlimited Support
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        $14 99 / Mo
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th">
                            </span>PREMIER</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                       <table class="table">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        60 Days of Cloud Recording
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        Up to 15 Cameras
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        Unlimited Support
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        $14 99 / Mo
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user">
                            </span>BASIC</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                       <table class="table">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        60 Days of Cloud Recording
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        Up to 15 Cameras
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        Unlimited Support
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        $14 99 / Mo
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could include the markup for both desktop and mobile on the same page and use the Bootstrap `hidden-xs` and `visible-sm` classes on your `.containers` (or whatever you want to show/hide). See [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities)

Comment: I'm not familiar with Bootstrap, so I was going to suggest media queries and display:none and stuff, but @zgood's suggestion seems more elegant.

Comment: If you're using Dreamweaver you might want to read up on FluidGridLayout. It basically creates media queries for you. Alternatively, you can create media queries and diy. Bootstrap as @zgood mentioned is another good method. At a last resort, however, you can use JavaScript/jQuery, however that should be used as a last resort. (Why?: Some people actually disable JS, crazy huh?!)

Answer (score 0):

You can also create media queries based on screen width then link them
within the head of your html doc. You would have to create separate styles for each view.

example

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-device-width: 768px)" href="tablet.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="phone.css" />
```

Just hide/show divs  using the css display property based on screen width.

As best practice be sure to combine all custom css into one file.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries